# How to identify which calendar is my default calendar at iCloud.com

Tags: icloud, icalendar, webdav, caldav

```
<d:propfind xmlns:d='DAV:' xmlns:cs='{0}' xmlns:c='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav'>
                                              <d:prop>
                                                 <d:resourcetype />
                                                 <d:displayname />
                                                 <cs:getctag />
                                                 <c:supported-calendar-component-set />
                                                 <d:current-user-privilege-set/>
                                                <d:calendar-access />
                                                <c:schedule-default-calendar-URL />
                                              </d:prop>
                                        </d:propfind>
```

Above is my request to fetch all calendars.
How to distinguish between default calendar and other calendars after reading response. For every calendar following is common in response-:

```
<propstat><prop><calendar-access /><schedule-default-calendar-URL xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav" /></prop><status>HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found</status></propstat>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [RFC6638 4.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6638#section-4.3) you should get a value for the

`schedule-default-calendar-URL`

property on the Inbox collection. And, well, that is the default calendar ;-)

Comment: Yes, but I am not getting it for any calendar.

Comment: Following is what I am getting for every calendar -:
<propstat><prop><calendar-access /><schedule-default-calendar-URL xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav" /></prop><status>HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found</status></propstat>

Comment: Am I missing something? Above posted question is my sample request.
Thanks!

Comment: Well, your request has `xmlns:cs='{0}'`, which is not what you want. Wrt the URL property, this is not defined on calendars, it is defined on the Inbox collection. So it is perfectly normal that you get a property-404 on calendars. Maybe show us the full response you are receiving from the server (add that to your question).

Comment: I forget to mention that I replace {0} to "http://calendarserver.org/ns/" in code using string.Format(). Its a typo mistake.

Comment: There is strange situation for some calendar account I am getting href inside tag 'schedule-default-calendar-URL' but for some calendar account I am not getting href for any calendar inside 'schedule-default-calendar-URL'.